# why the node laser_filters fails after updated

Tags: ros, laser-filters, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all. I am using "[Hokuyo URG04LX UG01](http://en.manu-systems.com/URG-04LX-UG01.shtml)" and trying to test a ros wrapper for [people detector](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Espinello/people2D.html) by detecting legs.

Naturally, the node "[laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters)" was used for preprocessing the laser data.  In the beginning, some warnings about laser_filters promted me that I should update laser_filters node. And the results of running leg detctor was not good. So I updated the "laser_filters" node by "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-laser-filters" and run the wrapper for people detector. I got following errors:

```
process[laser_filter-3]: started with pid [5766]
 /opt/ros/hydro/lib/laser_filters/scan_to_scan_filter_chain: symbol lookup error:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/laser_filters/scan_to_scan_filter_chain: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb
[laser_filter-3] process has died [pid 5766, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/laser_filters/scan_to_scan_filter_chain   __name:=laser_filter __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ff5f27c4-8cbf-11e4-8214-2cd05a75d967/laser_filter-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ff5f27c4-8cbf-11e4-8214-2cd05a75d967/laser_filter-3*.log
respawning...
[laser_filter-3] restarting process
```

The config yaml file for laser filter is shown here:

```
scan_filter_chain:
- name: range
  type: LaserScanRangeFilter
  params: 
     lower_threshold: 0.0001
     upper_threshold: .inf
- name: shadows
  type: ScanShadowsFilter
  params:
    min_angle: 10
    max_angle: 172
    neighbors: 1
    window: 1
- name: interpolation
  type: InterpolationFilter
```

My ros version is hydro.  Looking forward to give my any advices. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200077/why-the-node-laser_filters-fails-after-updated/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer. This is because of the incompatible between roslib and updated laser_filters. After updating roslib, the problem was solved. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) with karma: 279 on 2014-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1